# EF Core ValueGeneratedOnAdd does not work with postgresql

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, npgsql

When using ConfigurationDbContext from `Assembly IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage`

And seeding database with `IdentityServer4.Models.Client` entity
[image]

I get the following error: **PostgresException: 23502: null value in column "Id" violates not-null constraint**

I took a look at the database and it turns out that the column is of type `integer`, even though I'd expect it to be `serial`.
[image]

Below you can see parts of migration code responsible for column creation:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Clients",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity("IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

Basing on documentation https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html,
calling `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` on a `integer` column should result in `serial` type in the database.

Any thoughs on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing

```
.Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
```

to

```
.Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)
```

has solved the problem.

Comment: That's right. The original migration was generated on SqlServer, and so does not work as-is on Npgsql. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers for more information on working with multiple providers.

Comment: in such case, i would recommend deleteing all migrations (as well as dropping database) and re-adding the initial migration with Npgsql configured. this will generate the migrations properly for postgresql

Answer (score 5):

Extension method for common providers. Put this code anywhere in your project that also contains the migrations.

```
namespace MyNamespace;

/// <summary>Entity framework extensions</summary>
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Add identity annotation for sqlite, mysql, postgres and sql server </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">Property builder</param>
    public static void HasIdentityAnnotation<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.HasAnnotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true)
        .HasAnnotation("MySql:ValueGeneratedOnAdd", true)
        .HasAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
            Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Metadata.NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)
        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me if I'm being ignorant. But where is this extension method supposed to go? Is it inside the migrations file created?

Comment: using serial columns is not recommended anymore. instead, opt for "identity columns" which were introduced to replace serial columns in PostgreSQL version 10.